# How can I make the program ready in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

I made a simple program and now I want to make it ready for the user, I always open it in simulation but how can I turn this thing into a program for others?

Comment: You need to use "LabVIEW AppBuilder". Google that term and you should get lots of instructions (posting as a comment because it is late and I don't have time to write more complete info, but I thought maybe you were stuck and this would help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to create a Project.
2. Develop your application taking care of paths, make them relative to Application directory preferably.
3. In Build Specificacionts you can create an Application (EXE) end installers. I recomend you that compile every mayor change and test the functionality is the same as the code.
   You will need application builder license or professional LabVIEW.
   There is a lot of help and info in https://forums.ni.com/